# How can I access SecurityContext programmatically but not through annotation in CXF JAX-RS?

Tags: annotations, cxf, jax-rs

I'm trying to access the javax.ws.rs.core.SecurityContext in my class programmatically and not using `@Context` annotations, is a way to do it?

e.g. Spring provide implementation like `SecurityContextHolder.getContext()` that get the object from the `ThreadLocal`; is there similar implementation available in CXF JAX-RS?